# Unity Android touch not working as expected

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm using this touch script to show some effect when touching screen:

```
var ParticleA : GameObject;
//var bulletHole : GameObject;

function Update () {

    var hit : RaycastHit;
    // Use Screen.height because many functions (like this one) start in the bottom left of the screen, while MousePosition starts in the top left
    var ray : Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 200)) 
        {
            var newparA = Instantiate(ParticleA, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
            //var hitRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal);
            //Instantiate(bulletHole, hit.point, hitRotation);
            Destroy(newparA, 12.0);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work on Android. When touching, it just shows effect on center screen, not where my finger is actually touching.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` (that's for mouse... as the name says).

Use `Input.touches`: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html

Answer (score 1):

This code is in C#. Put this Code inside your **UPDATE()** function. It will work in Unity Editor as well as on Android Platform.

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray;
public Camera hudCamera;


            if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor) 
            {
                ray = hudCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) 
                    {
                        if (hit.collider == transform.collider) 
                        {
                            // Here transform.collider is the collider of that gameobject on which you attach this script
                            // Your Rest of the Logic Here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // This Will work on Android Device ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            else if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
            {   
                if (Input.touchCount > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
                    {
                        ray = hudCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
                        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                        {
                            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                            {
                                if (hit.collider == transform.collider)
                                {
                                    // Here transform.collider is the collider of that gameobject on which you attach this script
                                    // Your Rest of the Logic Here
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                        {
                            // Logic for finger move on screen
                        }

                        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                        {
                            if (Input.GetTouch(i).fingerId == fingerId)
                            {
                                fingerId = -1;
                                // Logic when touch ends 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var ParticleA : GameObject;

    function Update () 
    {
        var hit : RaycastHit;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
            {
            if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Vector3.forward,out hit ))  
               {
                   var newparA =Instantiate(ParticleA, hit.point,Quaternion.identity );
               Destroy(newparA, 12.0);
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

var ParticleA : GameObject;

function Update () {

var hit : RaycastHit;

for (var touch : Touch in Input.touches) {

```
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

                            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touch.position);

                            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 200))

       {

                                var newparA = Instantiate(ParticleA, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);

        Destroy(newparA, 12.0);

       }

    }

            }
```

}